# Creating rinkeby account on windows using geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I have been following this guide https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc to create rinkeby test network account on geth. Is there any way to type the commands in step 3 in Windows? Because it is now optimized for mac and linux.

command is:

```
geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby attach ipc:$HOME/.rinkeby/geth.ipc console
```

Answer (score 1):

If you launch geth with

```
geth --rinkeby
```

Then you can attach to that instance using the default IPC file `\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`

```
geth --rinkeby attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

On windows you can change the name of the IPC file but you cannot change its path.

If you launch with a data directory

```
geth --rinkeby --datadir c:\Users\adam\rinkeby --ipcpath geth-eve2.ipc
```

Then you can attach with

```
geth --rinkeby --datadir c:\Users\adam\rinkeby attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth-eve2.ipc
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the console window as well, use :

```
geth --rinkeby attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc console
```